# Creating Labels in google maps API crashes the app when the label count is more

Tags: android, performance, api, google-maps

I am creating labels for my features in google maps in this way:

```
 IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(loc_network.this);
                                        iconFactory.setBackground(TRANSPARENT_DRAWABLE);
                                        iconFactory.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGeneratorTextStyle);
                                        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().

                                                position(bounds.getCenter());

                                        BitmapDescriptor labelIcon =BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(Common_name[i]));
                                        markerOptions.icon(labelIcon);
                                        Marker label=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                                        label.setTag("building");
                                        label.setVisible(false);
                                        pointmarker.add(label);
```

The method iconFactory.makeIcon is makinbg the icon from dynamic text and if my labels are more the app crashes after some time please suggest other alternative easy way to make labels in google maps android api. Also I cannot use info window for this. It seems the iconFactory.makeIcon() is not working/memory efficient for more features.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of posting your variable initialization and requesting alternatives for your technology (which is considered off topic) add a description of the behavior of your app that occurs before the error, so we can help you solve it.

Comment: Have you tried IconGenerator from the Google Maps Android API [Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)?